# i would like to know how to make active voice

Tags: grammar, active-voice

What would be the active voice of below mentioned sentence.

> "India is known as peace loving country"

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> The citizens of India know it as a peace-loving country.
>   The world knows India as a peace-loving country.
>   India has a reputation of being a peace-loving country.
>   India is a peace-loving country.

Depending on what you are trying to express, any of those would work.

---

In a grammar course I took a while ago, the teacher provided a humorous test to see if a sentence was constructed in a passive sense or not.

Assuming it doesn't already end with *by something*, if you can add *by zombies* to it and it still makes sense, then it's likely passive:

> The window was broken *by zombies*.
>   The shop was robbed *by zombies*.
>   The night's silence was interrupted *by zombies*.

Your example sentence qualifies and my rephrased versions don't.